# Not able to remove a file

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, rm, removeall

Am not able to delete a file called 'go' in my bash home directory. I tried rm -r go..it dint work.it showed permission denied.as am a beginner I really can't figure it out how such a directory was  created.please help me with this

Comment: use `sudo rm -f go`

Comment: Am using a non rooted Android device bro..

Comment: Check the permissions (`ls -l go`) and please show us the output.

Comment: can you list the file by name: `ls go` vs `ls *go*`; if the former returns nothing but the latter displays the file then there other characters (besides the letters `g` and `o`) in the filename

Comment: Permissions showed as dwrx

Comment: both ls go n ls *go showed list of files in it

Comment: Show the exact output of `ls -ld go`. It certainly does NOT display just the string _dwrx_. Put such information into your question, not into a comment.